# Json data with key-value par is not getting populated on JQgrid

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

I am trying to execute a sample fiddle with Jqgrid and Json Data population.

Here is the fiddle , working with static data, http://jsfiddle.net/aUDHx/2/

But when i try to use the same with dymamic data, it is not populating the data on the jqgrid.

```
<table id="grid"></table>
<div id="gridPager"></div>
<br/>
<a href="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalAdjacencyTree4.htm">Another local adjaceny example</a>

var mydata="[";
//var mydata;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
mydata=mydata+'{id: i, label:"No " + i, number:"02200220", status:"OPEN"}';
    mydata=mydata+",";        
}     
mydata= mydata.slice(0,-1);
mydata=mydata+"]";
alert(mydata);
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(mydata);
alert(obj);

    /*[
    {id: "1", label:"No 1", number:"02200220", status:"OPEN"},
    {id: "1", label:"No 1", number:"02200220", status:"OPEN"},
    {id: "1", label:"No 1", number:"02200220", status:"OPEN"},
    {id: "1", label:"No 1", number:"02200220", status:"OPEN"}
];*/

var grid = $("#grid");

grid.jqGrid({
    //data: obj, // doesn't work
    datatype: "local",
    colNames: ['Id', 'Label', 'Number', 'Status'],
    colModel: [
    { name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype: "int"},
    { name: 'label', index: 'label', width: 180, sorttype: "string"},
    { name: 'number', index: 'number', width: 120, sorttype: "float" },
    { name: 'status', index: 'status', width: 120, sorttype: "string" } ],
    gridview: true,
    sortname: 'id',
    treeGrid: true,
    loadonce: true,
    treeGridModel: 'adjacency',
    treedatatype: 'local',
    ExpandColumn: 'label',
    height: 'auto',
    pager : "#gridPager",
    caption: "Stack Overflow Adjacency Example"
});


// we have to use addJSONData to load the data
grid[0].addJSONData({
total: 1,
page: 1,
records: obj.length,
rows: obj
});
```

What is that I am missing here, Can some one help me in this,I am very new to Jquery.

With JSON.Stringify(), its is printing empty grid..

```
var mydata="[";
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    mydata=mydata+{"id" : "i", "label":"No ", "number":"02200220", "status":"OPEN"};
    mydata=mydata+",";        
}     
mydata= mydata.slice(0,-1);
mydata=mydata+"]";
alert(mydata);
var obj = JSON.stringify(mydata);
alert(obj);
var grid = $("#grid");

grid.jqGrid({
    //data: obj, // doesn't work
    datatype: "local",
    colNames: ['Id', 'Label', 'Number', 'Status'],
    colModel: [
    { name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype: "int"},
    { name: 'label', index: 'label', width: 180, sorttype: "string"},
    { name: 'number', index: 'number', width: 120, sorttype: "float" },
    { name: 'status', index: 'status', width: 120, sorttype: "string" } ],
    gridview: true,
    sortname: 'id',
    treeGrid: true,
    loadonce: true,
    treeGridModel: 'adjacency',
    treedatatype: 'local',
    ExpandColumn: 'label',
    height: 'auto',
    pager : "#gridPager",
    caption: "Stack Overflow Adjacency Example"
});


// we have to use addJSONData to load the data
grid[0].addJSONData({
total: 1,
page: 1,
records: 10,
rows: obj
});
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Don't create JSON by hand, use `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: I don't see any way that your `for` loop could be creating that JSON correctly. You have `+ i` inside quotes, the concatenation won't be done.

Comment: And in JSON, all the keys have to be quoted, so it should be `"id": "1"`.

Comment: yes Barmar.. I tried all things yu mentioned earlier, but its creating empty grid without data, What is that I am missing here? Edited the question with JSON.Stringify()

Comment: Why are you making a JSON string in the first place? Just use your loop to create an array of objects, and pass that to jQgrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use JSON, just build the array of objects directly:

```
var obj = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    obj.push({
        id: i,
        label: "No " + i,
        number: "02200220",
        status: "OPEN"
    });
}
```

The purpose of JSON is to allow you to pass objects and arrays between machines, such as in an AJAX call. But if you're creating the data in Javascript, there's no need to convert it to a string.

Comment: Worked like Charm..!! Thanq you so very much Barmar..!!